# not able to reinstall ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, grub2

i am new to ubuntu(new to linux).i have installed ubuntu 14.04 lts a few days ago and encrypted the disk. due to some reason i decided to reinstall the same with help of usb stick but it failed to do so . the reason may be the encryption(i was thinking that reinstalling totally reset everything because i have the pass-phrase of encrypted disk). now whenever i am booting the gnu grub 2.02 is appearing. i am also unable to reinstall.
please somebody help to step forward. please help me step forward!
 is there any criteria to decrypt the same and reinstalling the again...??

i am not able post the screenshots images here!

Comment: please....please..somebody help me!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Please hit the [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/687550/edit)-Link below your question and explain what happens when you try to boot from your USB-Stick. What do you expect to happen and how exactly it fails. Please add what you tried to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are in the live USB/CD you need to create a new the partition table.
To do this open up a terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T type in

> sudo gparted-pkexec

Now make sure you have selected the drive that is encrypted, Then click on Device menu and then click on create a partition table then create a msdos partition table. You shoud be fine with installing Ubuntu.